# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')

Tags: reactjs, json

Getting an error while fetching data from an API the actual data I need is in response.
But when I try to access it just shows up as undefined. I added a loading function but that
does not seem to fix it.

Ex Json (The original is too big)

```
{
    "request": {
     
    },
    "response": [
      {
      Data I want here
       }
```

choose.js

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(
  //example API key 
      "https://airlabs.co/api/v9/flights?api_key=2a6ae284-575d-41d8-948a-b789734174dd&arr_icao=VOBL"
    )

      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

{data.response.map((post) => {

})
```

Full code link - https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wood-meecre?file=/choose.js:2042-2072

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with the loading state being `true`, because at the initial render you don't yet have `data`.

Also move the rendering that you do inside the `map` into its own component, otherwise you get a runtime error about too many hooks:

```
{data.response.map((post) => (
        <Inner post={post} />
      ))}
```

(Here the component that renders each flight data is simply named "Inner")

You can see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wind-1tflcu?file=/choose.js) for full demo.